# Google maps geolocation bug with webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3, google-geolocation

I need to use Google maps geolocation in one of my projects. I went to official Google maps javascript API website, used their code and everything worked fine couple days ago.

But now it doesn't work, it displays only "*ERROR: The Geolocation service failed*" message. It happens only in webkit browsers (Chrome, Firefox, etc.), IE works flawlessly. I checked several threads here on Stackoverflow, which say that you should launch your website from webserver and not directly from file, because webkit browsers have some file:// restrictions in terms of location.

But the weird part is, that for me it doesn't work on webserver and even on official Google website ([Google geolocation example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation)). I can see just error message described above.

Could it be some sort of bug in webkit browsers lately or bad configuration (FYI in Chrome I have location allowed for all websites) ? My version of Chrome is 36.0.1985.125, Firefox version 24.6.0 (probably some company restrictions) and IE 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically geoclocation is a webservice, each browser may use a different service-provider to retrieve the desired data.

When you don't get a result it's no bug, it simply means that your location may not be detected based on the given details(the details will depend on the used hardware)

IE requests the Microsoft Location Service, while Chrome(and usually Firefox too) use the Google Locations Service.

When a Service is not able to resolve your location you will see the mentioned error-message.

So this is no browser-related issue(because the source is the requested location-service, not the browser), and it's no bug at all, because an error because of a unresolved location is a valid response.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Looks like you are right, because I tried to use WiFi instead of Ethernet connection and it worked. Looks like some company policies to restrict geolocation on Ethernet. I was just confused, because a week ago it worked without any problems.